# How to join on a row with max value

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: households, voters, door_knocks

Each household can have several voters associated with it. Each household can also have several door knocks associated with it.

I'm trying to pull together all the voters in a household and the date of the last door_knock from the door_knocks table and I'm having trouble figuring out the proper query syntax. Here is my latest attempt:

```
SELECT households.hh_id, voters.id
FROM households
INNER JOIN voters ON households.hh_id = voters.hh_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(dk.date), dk.hh_id FROM door_knocks dk GROUP BY dk.date) dks
ON dks.hh_id = households.hh_id
WHERE households.street = ?
```

The above query pulls up one result for each door knock, however. I just want the the date from the last door knock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what it sounds like you're hoping for conceptually is a table that lists the last date of a knock for each houshold.
You'd like to join against that table  and combine it with the voters and the households.

what your query does is give you a table of all the dates (group by dk.date) and for each date list all the households.

If you group by hh_id instead, then you will get the max date for each given household.

```
SELECT households.hh_id, voters.id, dks.max_date
FROM households
INNER JOIN voters ON households.hh_id = voters.hh_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(dk.date) as max_date, dk.hh_id FROM door_knocks dk GROUP BY dk.hh_id dks
ON dks.hh_id = households.hh_id
WHERE households.street = ?
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm having one other problem, though. The actual date doesn't appear in the result. When I try putting `dk.date`, `dks.date`, or `doork_knocks.date` into the first part of the query, I get unknown column.

Comment: @StevieD answer updated  If this answers your question please accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. One other issue came up I just noticed. I want to include households with no entries in door knocks table. A left join will fix that? I’d test it but I’m on my mobile right now.